# Custom animate chart with jquery and html 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pie-chart

Need to create this chart in html5 with animation and chart update on select change.
[Chart Image Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RL75l.png)

Comment: Can anyone guide me please

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this by using an HTML5 chart library like [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/)
with some CSS modifications... Just an idea.

[Pie-Chart Doc](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#doughnut-pie-chart)

Comment: Thanks Nutt, I have tried this but I need combined two in one chart as you see in attached images. Please left me know if there is any possibility to combined two into one